# Alfresco web service response before executing rule/workflow

Tags: web-services, response, alfresco, jbpm

My application drops a file in alfresco space and waits for a response. The problem is that alfresco sends the response after executing the rule on the space which triggers the workflow. That takes too long. I want alfresco to send the web service response first and then execute the rule/workflow. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run the rule asynchronously by checking the "Run rule in background" checkbox upon rule configuration. This effectively detaches the rule execution from the request processing transaction.

When running rules asynchronously, make sure you have a proper failure handling as failures in the rule executions won't appear in the web service response anymore.